# Opposite of Nearest?

Tags: functions, nearest

There is an useful function `Nearest` in Mathematica, which finds the element in the aggregate given as its 1st argument that is nearest to its 2nd argument. It is very useful when we want to find the point out from a set which is the nearest to an arbitrary reference point.

On the other side, if we want to find the farthest point in a set from the reference point, a `Farthest` function would be useful. But looking at the documentation in the Mathematica v10.0.1, I was unable to find such an function or anything like one. Am I missing something?

This is a question out of curiosity, because I can get the farthest value constructing my own function considering euclidean distance. However, I would expect Mathematica to have in-built function that is already optimized.

Comment: Wouldn't negating the distance help? `Nearest[{{1.5, .6}, {2, 0}, {1.25, 1.25}}, {0, 0}, DistanceFunction -> (-EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] &)]`.

Comment: @J.M. Great coding. Looking at your answer, am I right that you have used the core property (as it looks) of `Nearest[]` to find the lowest `DistanceFunction` value? In the case of farthest point the negative `EuclideanDistance` is the lowest number.

Comment: @J.M. Additionally, why considering only `-EuclideanDistance` does not work?

Comment: `-EuclideanDistance` doesn't work because it is neither a function nor a expression that evaluates to a function; it is `Times[-1, EuclideanDistance]`

Comment: You'll want to use `DistanceFunction -> Composition[Minus, EuclideanDistance]` if you don't like slots.

Comment: @J.M. Not knowing how `Nearest` works, I feel a bit uncomfortable about the fact that this does not satisfy the properties of a mathematical *distance function*. What if the algorithm used by `Nearest` assumes some of these properties?  Perhaps it's better to explicitly use `Method -> "Scan"`?  Do you know if this method simply tests the distance to each point separately, as the name would suggest?  Maybe the default is *always* `"Scan"` for a custom `DistanceFunction`?

Comment: @Szabolcs, that caveat is why I did not post an answer for the time being. It seems to work if I use `Nearest[]` on numbers or points, but I have not tested negation on anything else nontrivial.

Comment: @m_goldberg Your proposal of `Times[-1, EuclideanDistance]` does not work. However, `Composition[Minus, EuclideanDistance]` does work.

Comment: @J.M. It is not that I do not like slots, I just do not fully understand the context in which they are used. For example, in your first comment I can assume that `#1` and `#2` are some arguments. Now, I do not know what `&` does to the expression in the round brackets and I have no idea how Mathematica knows that `#1` and `#2` should be first and second argument from _data_ as stated in the definition of `Nearest`.

Comment: @Mike he was not *proposing* `Times[-1, EuclideanDistance]` but rather explaining that `-EuclideanDistance` evaluates to that expression, and that *it does not work* because it is not a function.  That said it would be nice shorthand if `-function` worked the way you thought it did.

Comment: I think the best built-in would be MaximalBy, using an appropriate 
function for the maximization: `furthest[lst_,pt_]:=MaximalBy[lst,EuclideanDistance[pt,#]&]`.

Comment: I don't think there is a particularly efficient way to go about this, at least not in arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. I was explaining why `-EuclideanDistance` does not work.

Comment: `farthest[lst_, ele_] := 
 Nearest[lst, ele, Infinity] // Cases[#, Last@#] &;` does the job pretty quickly on my turdbook...

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the data:

```
data = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {10000, 2}];
```

and want `Furthest[data -> "Index", data, 4]`. Select the vertices of the convex hull and add to those the vertices of the new convex hull (of data without already found vertices). Stop after the 4th convex hull. In this code I only include these vertices in `Nearest`

```
element = Nest[Join[MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[Complement[data, #]]], #] &, {}, 4];
index = Lookup[PositionIndex[data], element][[All, 1]];
res = Transpose[index[[#]] & /@ Transpose[Take[Nearest[
  element -> "Index", data, Length[element]], All, {-1, -4, -1}]]];
```

I hope the `DistanceFunction` you are using allow this. Otherwise maybe you can still do it after some transformation of data.

I also tried using `Compile` with `Ordering[#, -4]` to avoid `Nearest[, ,Length[element]]`, but it was only slightly faster, and I am not sure if `Parallelization` might cause problems for `Ordering`

```
c2 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Function[u, #2[[u]]] /@ Reverse[Ordering[Plus @@ ((x - #)^2), -4]],
      Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}] &[Transpose[element], index];
```